# statsmodel summary col getting a latex key error?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I've been getting a key error when using the summary_col function.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.iolib.summary2 import summary_col
Y = [0,1,0,0,1,1,1]
X = [5,10,15,20,25,2,7]
logit = sm.Logit(Y,X)
fit = logit.fit()
print(fit.summary())
logit_output = summary_col([fit],stars=True)
print(logit_output.as_latex())
```

gets me a "Key Error: '\m'". Surprisingly, fit.summary().as_latex() does not return this error.

Comment: Can you please add which package or module you are using? Or do you use self written code? My first guess is, that there is as typo in `logit_output.as_latex()` where someone wanted to add a newline character `\n` and instead wrote `\m` which is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm using import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.iolib.summary2 import summary_col

Comment: For debugging help, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the input and the full error traceback.  Please also add `statsmodels` as an additional tag to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reading a bit in the code and I think you are triggering a bug in the code of statsmodels.

Here is my wild explanation. The function `summary_col` returns an object of the `Summary` class and sets `_merge_latex = True`. In `.as_latex()` the next if-caluse is enabled. Here is the link to the [source](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/26dbb94299e5c12221b157ee5837691b6d24a755/statsmodels/iolib/summary2.py#L229) where I found the code below:

```
if self._merge_latex:
    # create single tabular object for summary_col
    tab = re.sub(to_replace, r'\\midrule\n', tab)
```

If you call `fit.summary().as_latex()` then `_merge_latex = False` by default. So you don't get into this part and don't get the same error.

Right now I am not sure what is wrong. I could think of two cases:

1. `re.sub()` is only called once and there is a leftover of stuff you want to replace
2. `r'\\midrule\n'` is wrong in this line and it shoul be `'\\midrule\n'` instead.

To make some progress you have to build a minimal example.
To disable the error to see if I am on the right trake, please add

```
logit_output._merge_latex = False
```

before your rerun

```
print(logit_output.as_latex())
```

your code and check if the error changes. This may generate an output you don't want.

Comment: Do you consider to open an issue on [GutHub](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues)? Mabye this is a problem other people will run into it, too.